# I need to call an object from a class and add to it a deposit amount

Tags: c#

So I have a class called `BankAcc`. I then created an instance of this class in Program.cs:

```
BankAcc account1 = new BankAcc("Jorge", 1000, "CA", "$", 15556667);
```

Where 1000 is the current amount of money in the account and 15556667 is the number of the account.

I want the console to ask the user to enter an **account number** and then make a deposit into that account (adding the deposit to the current U$S 1000).

How do I do this?

CODE BankAcc.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dominio
{
class Cuentas
{
    #region Instancias
    private string titular;
    private decimal saldo;
    private string tipoCuenta;
    private string moneda;
    private int numero;
    #endregion

    #region Propiedades
    public string Titular
    {
        get { return this.titular; }
        set { this.titular = value; }
    }

    public decimal Saldo
    {
        get { return this.saldo; }
        set { this.saldo = value; }
    }

    public string TipoCuenta
    {
        get { return this.tipoCuenta; }
        set { this.tipoCuenta = value; }
    }

    public string Moneda
    {
        get { return this.moneda; }
        set { this.moneda = value; }
    }

    public int Numero
    {
        get { return this.numero; }
        set { this.numero = value; }
    }


    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Cuentas(string titular, decimal saldo, string tipoCuenta, string moneda, int numero)
    {
        this.Titular = titular;
        this.Saldo = saldo;
        this.TipoCuenta = tipoCuenta;
        this.Moneda = moneda;
        this.Numero = numero;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Validaciones
   
    public bool Deposito(decimal deposito, string moneda)
    {
        if()
    }
    #endregion

    #region Override

    #endregion


 }
}
```

CODE Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dominio;

namespace Ejercicio2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cuentas cuenta1 = new Cuentas("Jorge", 1000, "CA", "$", 15556667);
            Cuentas cuenta2 = new Cuentas("Maria", 2500, "CC", "U$S", 45468777);
        

        decimal deposito = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: You'll need to store all of the created bank accounts in something like an array then loop through each one to find a match with the inputted account number and the account number associated with each stored bank account.

Comment: @Mureinik I just edited the post, is in spanish, I hope this doesn't cause any trouble.

Comment: @vc74 How do I do that? I will read something about it since I've never heard about it.

Comment: @IvanNL My question is irrelevant now you've posted the code. Basically with a mutable class you'd invoke a method updating the account's balance while with the immutable approach, updating would build a new instance.

Comment: @IvanNL Do you that you can use auto properties since c# 3.0 ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot Thanks!

Comment: Basically you to `Saldo+=deposito;` in `Deposito()` if the currency matches the reference currency, and you convert before if it does not. This part is extremely basic. The convert part is more interesting: do you put it in `Cuentas` ? (hint: separate responsabilities in separate classes) Are the rates defined in the class, or in a file which is updated every T ? It looks like a service: you want to test it and use an interface, and do dependency injection (DI); this DI helps to test your class, and make classes losely coupled, which reduces maintenance and engineering/project cost.

Comment: You could use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1) to associate each instance with its account number: `Dictionary<int, Cuentas>`.  This will allow you to retrieve the instance for the entered account and manipulate.

Comment: @IvanNL Also what you want is to have `public decimal Saldo {get; protected set;}` so the money is modified only through methods that will do the proper checking via `Deposito()` and `Retirada()`. You hence avoid any wild `account1.Saldo += hackedAmount;` from outside your type.

Comment: Yet, as for the money, there is an amount that always ships with a currency (high cohesion properties and methods are good candidates to be part of a new type ). It would be wise to create a new class that gathers `Saldo` and `Moneda`, this is a single responsability. This new class can have `ConvertCurrency()` methods. That would be a much better design.